# JavaScript: Create Button Along with TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I am quite new to the JavaScript/HTML/CSS world so try to bear with me.

Right now, I have created a function, `insertText()`, that when called creates a textarea into a specified div.

However, I would also like the function to create a Button directly above the textarea. I have tried to use a similar method to create a button as I did the textarea and am not receiving an error, however, I am not seeing a button either.

```
function insertText() {
$("text_div")
.append(' <textarea placeholder="Input Value"/> ' )
.append(' <input type="button" name="Confirm" value="Confirm"/> ')
.css({
    left: cursor_x + "px",
    top: cursor_y + "px",
)};
};
```

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: More specific and changed title.

Comment: You might want to post any code that you have tried or else they are going to close this question..

Comment: You might be new (and that's fine, we all started somewhere, once!) but we still need you to take the lead. What HTML are you starting with? How far through, with the JavaScript, did you get? Where did you get stuck? What, specifically, did you want help with? We don't really offer 'guidance,' since that's too open-ended (and more of a discussion), we do answer objective questions about specific problems though.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the heads up- I'll edit my question to be more specific. Just a moment!

Answer (score 0):

You have a missplaced `)` at the 8th line. Should be `});` instead of `)};`.
Code:

```
function insertText() {
    $("#text_div")
    .append(' <textarea placeholder="Input Value"/> ' )
    .append(' <input type="button" name="Confirm" value="Confirm"/> ')
    .css({
        left: cursor_x + "px",
        top: cursor_y + "px"
    });
};
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DHaUD/